# How to use SQL Order By statement to sort results case insensitive?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a SQLite database that I am trying to sort by Alphabetical order.  The problem is, SQLite doesn't seem to consider A=a during sorting, thus I get results like this:

A
B
C
T
a
b
c
g

I want to get:

A
a
b
B
C
c
g
T

What special SQL thing needs to be done that I don't know about?

```
SELECT * FROM NOTES ORDER BY title
```

Comment: And what is the more efficient way to do it? "ORDER BY TITLE COLLATE NOCASE" or "ORDER BY LOWER(TITLE)". (FYI, in my case, running on Android, i.e. SQLite)

Answer (score 280, accepted):

You can also do `ORDER BY TITLE COLLATE NOCASE`.

Edit: If you need to specify `ASC` or `DESC`, add this after `NOCASE` like

```
ORDER BY TITLE COLLATE NOCASE ASC
```

or

```
ORDER BY TITLE COLLATE NOCASE DESC
```

Comment: Is "ORDER BY TITLE COLLATE NOCASE" more efficient than "ORDER BY LOWER(TITLE)"?

Comment: THAT SUCKS! isn't it?  Wow!  why the heck SQLite is making it case sensitive for sorting....  doesn't fit in my mind... unfortunately!

Comment: @Vincy: I don't see what's so weird about case-sensitive string comparison.  That's how the `<`, `==`, etc. operators work by default in every programming language that I'm familiar with.

Comment: @dan04 how often you need a string that has to be case sensitive?  that is why it is ridiculous.  who in the world care about cases while sorting a string?  The only place I see the advantage is for authentication or password validation!  That is why be default it has to be CASE INSENSITIVE, imo!

Comment: This usually won't work out of the box, if the database uses UTF8. (Notice that the title doesn't refer to just SQLite.) In this case, the suggestion to use lower() or upper() below is the one that works.

Comment: it's make database reading speed too much lower than before , do you have an idea how to increase speed?

Answer (score 114):

You can just convert everything to lowercase for the purposes of sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM NOTES ORDER BY LOWER(title);
```

If you want to make sure that the uppercase ones still end up ahead of the lowercase ones, just add that as a secondary sort:

```
SELECT * FROM NOTES ORDER BY LOWER(title), title;
```

Comment: I'm sorting by multiple columns, do I have to put the LOWER around each one?

Comment: Yes, there's no way to change the behavior of ORDER BY to be case-insensitive.

Comment: Is there any difference between 'UPPER' and 'LOWER'

Comment: For this purpose, no they will both achieve the same effect, which is to make the case of all items the same.

Comment: They differ only for the characters [\]^_` .

Comment: does not work for oracle sql when the selected set includes a union.

Comment: @dan04 That would happen with ASCII order but I'm seeing ``VALUES ('lower'), ('['), (']'), ('^'), ('_'), ('`'), ('UPPER') ORDER BY upper(column1);`` as well as `BY lower(column1)` both return \` ^ _ [ ] lower UPPER order.  (postgres 9.5, `SHOW lc_collate` outputs nothing, LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 env vars).  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_do_my_strings_sort_incorrectly.3F explains locale sorting normally compares letters before punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM NOTES ORDER BY UPPER(title)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But:  A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.