# ORDER in UNION ALL don't works

Tags: sqlite

first of all i'm sorry for my english.

I've two tables with same columns and i want to join both in SELECT and order by 'nombre'. My problem is that it don't work as I expect. For example:

**Table 1 (ListaAmbos):**

```
ID  nombre
1   Asaber
2   Zip
```

**Table 2 (Listax86):**

```
ID  nombre
24  rtywr
25  afaf
26  stftst'gdh
27  dgsdhttrh%%
28  Prueba
```

**What i want:**

```
ID  nombre
25  afaf
1   Asaber
27  dgsdhttrh%%
28  Prueba
24  rtywr
26  stftst'gdh
2   Zip
```

**What i get:**

```
ID  nombre
1   Asaber
28  Prueba
2   Zip
25  afaf
27  dgsdhttrh%%
24  rtywr<br>
26  stftst'gdh
```

Im using this query:

```
SELECT ID, nombre FROM ListaAmbos 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID, nombre FROM Listax86 
ORDER BY nombre ASC;
```

but don't work like i want... What im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying like this:-

```
 SELECT ID, nombre FROM ListaAmbos
 UNION ALL SELECT ID, nombre FROM Listax86 ORDER BY nombre COLLATE NOCASE ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting is upper case first, then lower case, which means you're using a case-sensitive collation. Change your query to:

```
...
ORDER BY nombre COLLATE NOCASE ASC
```

See also: [How to use SQL Order By statement to sort results case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413427/how-to-use-sql-order-by-statement-to-sort-results-case-insensitive)

Comment: Thanks for link friend :)