# How do I make DBIx::Class ignore case in ORDER BY with SQLite?

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbix-class

Typically SQLite's collation sorts case-sensitive. All capital letters come before small letters. But it's possible to tell SQLite in the `ORDER BY` clause to ignore that, [by doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2413833/1331451):

```
... ORDER BY foo COLLATE NOCASE ASC
```

But how do we do this with DBIx::Class?

Consider the following example, which deploys an SQLite database in memory with a table `foo` and one comlumn `bar`. The connection uses [the `quote_names` setting](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI#quote_names). It fills in the values `z Z b B a A` and then gets them back out using `all` on the ResultSet. I'll be using this setup in all my following examples. You need [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) and [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite) to run this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Foo::Schema::Result::Foo;
use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->table("foo");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns( "bar", { data_type => "text" }, );

package Foo::Schema;
use base 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->register_class( 'Foo' => 'Foo::Schema::Result::Foo' );

package main;
my $schema = Foo::Schema->connect(
    {
        dsn         => 'dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:',
        quote_names => 1,
    }
);
$schema->deploy;

$schema->resultset('Foo')->create( { bar => $_ } ) for qw(z Z b B a A);
my @all = $schema->resultset('Foo')->search(
    {},
    {
        order_by => { -asc => 'me.bar' },
    },
)->all;

# example code starts here

print join q{ }, map { $_->bar } @all;
```

The output of this is sorted case-sensitive.

```
A B Z a b z
```

Now of course I could sort it with Perl and make it case-insensitive, like this.

```
print join q{ }, sort { lc $a cmp lc $b } map { $_->bar } @all;
```

Now I get

```
A a B b Z z
```

But I can also use the `COLLATE NOCASE` if I query using the underlying DBI handle directly.

```
$schema->storage->dbh_do(
    sub {
        my ( $storage, $dbh, @args ) = @_;
        my $res = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
            "SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY bar COLLATE NOCASE ASC"
        );
        print "$_->[0] " for @$res;
    }
```

This gives us

```
a A b B z Z
```

I want DBIC to use the `COLLATE NOCASE`, but without running any SQL. I do not want to do any expensive string conversions in the `ORDER BY`, or do them later in Perl.

**How do I tell DBIx::Class to use the `COLLATE NOCASE` when ordering with SQLite?**

---

The following does not work:

```
order_by => { '-collate nocase asc' => 'me.bar' },
```

And this only works if [`quote_names`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI#quote_names) is not turned on.

```
order_by => { -asc => 'me.bar COLLATE NOCASE' },
```

It will produce this query and error message with the above example code.

> SELECT "me"."bar" FROM "foo" "me" ORDER BY "me"."bar COLLATE NOCASE"
>   ASC:  DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_prepare_sth(): DBI Exception:
>   DBD::SQLite::db prepare_cached failed: no such column: me.bar COLLATE
>   NOCASE [for Statement "SELECT "me"."bar" FROM "foo" "me" ORDER BY
>   "me"."bar COLLATE NOCASE" ASC"]

Or I could do it by converting to `upper` or `lower` in the `ORDER BY` clause using DBIC.

```
my @all = $schema->resultset('Foo')->search(
    {},
    {
        order_by => { -asc => 'lower(me.bar)' },
    },
)->all;

print join q{ }, map { $_->bar } @all;
```

This gives

```
a A b B z Z
```

without `quote_names` which is similar, but the other way around. (That's not my concern here), but also throws an error when `quote_names` is turned on.

> SELECT "me"."bar" FROM "foo" "me" ORDER BY "lower(me"."bar)" ASC: 
>   DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_prepare_sth(): DBI Exception:
>   DBD::SQLite::db prepare_cached failed: no such column: lower(me.bar)
>   [for Statement "SELECT "me"."bar" FROM "foo" "me" ORDER BY
>   "lower(me"."bar)" ASC"]

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to do this is with literal SQL, which means passing a scalar reference: `order_by => \'me.bar COLLATE NOCASE ASC'`. FWIW, this also works: `order_by => { -asc => \'me.bar COLLATE NOCASE' }`.

Comment: Do you want to write up an answer @Matt? Literal SQL is fine, even if it binds us to SQLite. In this case I don't care.

Comment: I was hesitant to post an answer because you said you didn't want to use any SQL, and because I wasn't sure (and still am not) if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: @matt it seems you read my post better than I did. You're right, I said that, but I meant the example using the dbh. ;) If there is a better answer we will find it. But this is a good start. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're comfortable using a very small amount of SQL, you can pass a scalar reference to denote literal SQL, and DBIC won't mess with it:

```
order_by => \'me.bar COLLATE NOCASE ASC'
```

Or, with just the bare minimum amount of literal SQL:

```
order_by => { -asc => \'me.bar COLLATE NOCASE' }
```

Note that this syntax is [technically discouraged](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#order_by), but I don't know of any other way to achieve what you're after:

> The old scalarref syntax (i.e. order_by => \'year DESC') is still
>   supported, although you are strongly encouraged to use the hashref
>   syntax as outlined above.

Comment: It's worth noting that the scalarref syntax `order_by => \SCALAR` is discouraged, but it implies that the scalarref-in-a-hashref syntax `order_by => { -asc => \SCALAR }` is still perfectly cromulent