# CursorLoader - order by in SQL is case insensitive

Tags: java, android, sql, android-cursorloader

I am trying to query information with a CursorLoader from my SQL database. How do I make the order case insensitive?

```
return new CursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, orderBy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413427/how-to-use-sql-order-by-statement-to-sort-results-case-insensitive) as source:

While ordering, you can "convert" the data to lower/upper case. Data retrieved won't be affected since you are changing the ORDER BY statement.

```
return new CursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, "UPPER(COLUMN_NAME)");
```