Sort order mismatch between SQLite and Javascript
I have this better-sqlite-3 statement that returns a list of products, first sorted by relevance (for search feature, it's 0 for all in this case), then by favorite and then by name A-Z.
    ORDER BY
        relevance DESC,
        preferito DESC,
        des_art   ASC

The products are displayed like so:
"ACCIUGA RIPIENA CREUZA"

"ACCIUGA RIPIENA baccalà"

I have a javascript function that I use to restore the list in case the favorite status changes, but then the products are displayed in alphabetical order ignoring the uppercase.
allProducts.sort((a, b) => {
    
    if (b.relevance !== a.relevance) {
        return b.relevance - a.relevance;
    }
    
    if (b.preferito !== a.preferito) {
        return b.preferito - a.preferito;
    }
    
    return a.des_art.localeCompare(b.des_art);
});

"ACCIUGA RIPIENA baccalà"

"ACCIUGA RIPIENA CREUZA"

How do I keep the same SQL behavior? I tried using
return a.des_art.localeCompare(b.des_art, undefined, { sensitivity: 'case', caseFirst: 'upper' }); but without changes.

Is "ACCIUGA RIPIENA CREUZA" meant to represent the 3 fields? So relevance = 'ACCIUGA', preferito = 'RIPIENA', des_art = 'CREUZA'? It would help if you added column-names to the sample output.

In SQL (regardless of the RDMBS), if you're depending on a particular sort-order w.r.t. case-sensitivity, accents, etc you should always specify an explicit COLLATION. SQLite has some quirks of its own: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413427/how-to-use-sql-order-by-statement-to-sort-results-case-insensitive

@Dai post updated. Relevance is 0 because the search is empty.

So, your question isn't at all about sorting on three fields, just about string sorting, right? Or does preferito affect the sort order here?

@VLAZ In this case preferito is just a part of the sorting, the question is why the sort for string is different from SQL and JS. C > b vs b > C.

To keep the same as SQLite's binary collation ordering, you should compare the strings using < and >. This ensures uppercase comes before lowercase, as their UTF-16 code units are smaller (e.g., 'A' is 65, 'a' is 97).
allProducts.sort((a, b) => {

    if (b.relevance !== a.relevance) {
        return b.relevance - a.relevance;
    }

    if (b.preferito !== a.preferito) {
        return b.preferito - a.preferito;
    }

    if (a.des_art < b.des_art) return -1;
    if (a.des_art > b.des_art) return 1;
    return 0;
});


This worked, but why localeCompare didn't?

localeCompare works on locale specific rules and can behave differently on different browsers.
